# Getting an input from outside the form to submit with it

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Okay, so I have an input

```
<input class="r" type="file" accept="image/*" id="work" capture="camera" name="Picture">
```

Later in the document i have a form

```
<form action="enterforms.php" method="post" onSubmit="return validate()">
```

which contains a hidden input

```
<input id="pic" type="file" name="Picture">
```

i need a way of either submitting the orginal input with the form or copying the first form into the second.

Some observations:

- neither clone  nor moving the original input will make it maintain the value of the file in the form
- I can get a "URL" of the file that will work as a src tag for an image
- I can't move input into the form because they're on separate pages in this pretty complex structure.

Basically, submitting the image is creates the form, but it pushes the input away from the user. (Its actually more complex but really hard to explain, if I need to I can go more into detail)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You say "I have an input…Later in the document i have a form", but then "I can't move input into the form because they're on separate pages". So is the input and form in the same page or not?

Comment: Im using a jquery mobile pagination structure, which asynchronously loads adjacent pages, so the page where one input will exist, the both will exist, then the other will exist,